# Distance calculation in query with slick database

Tags: scala, distance, slick, typesafe

I am using slick with scala to find the distance of the user to the closes spot. But I'm not sure how to properly do this with slick. I've tried different ways, but I keep getting errors with symbols or not getting the appropriate answers. The SQL query that I'm looking to convert is:

```
SELECT *, 3956 * 2 * sin(sqrt( pow(sin((spot_lat -
abs(lat)) * Pi/180 / 2),2) + cos(spot_lat * Pi/180 ) * cos(abs(lat) *  Pi/180) *
pow(sin((spot_lon – lon) *  Pi/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance 
FROM Spots
```

Where lat and lon have been given as inputs

Comment: Can you include the Scala you have been trying?

Comment: @Jonoabroad `val q = for { s <- globals.spots } yield (3956 * 2 * sin(sqrt( pow(sin((s.spot_lat - abs(lat)) * Pi/180 / 2),2) + cos(s.stop_lat * Pi/180 ) * cos(abs(lat) *  Pi/180) * pow(sin((s.spot_lon – lon) * Pi/180 / 2), 2) )) )`

Comment: @Jonoabroad `val newQuery = for {(latr, lonr) <- Parameters [(Double, Double)] u <- globals.spots if u.spot_lat >= latr && u.spot_lon >= lonr}yield u
val result = newQuery(lat, lon).list ` This one was more of a test to see if it would query

Comment: The model? I'll try and recreate it from the query.

Answer (score 1):

First, define your database trig functions so that they can be used by slick:

```
val dbSin = SimpleFunction.unary[Double, Double]("sin")
val dbCos = SimpleFunction.unary[Double, Double]("cos")
val dbSqrt = SimpleFunction.unary[Double, Double]("sqrt")
val dbPow = SimpleFunction.binary[Double, Double, Double]("pow")
val dbAbs = SimpleFunction.unary[Double, Double]("abs")
```

When you use these functions in a slick query, it generates the SQL query with calls to the database function. Also, make sure that the trig functions are defined in the database you are using. Read more about it at: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/userdefined.html

Now you can use these functions in your query:

```
import scala.math._
def distance(lat: Double, lon: Double) = globals.spots map { spot =>
    3956 * 2 * dbSin(dbSqrt(dbPow(dbSin((spot.splot_lat - Pi / 180.0 / 2.0), 2) +
        dbCos(spot.spot_lat * Pi / 180.0) * dbCos(dbAbs(lat) * Pi / 180.0) *
        dbPow(dbSin((spot.spot_lon - lon) * Pi / 180.0 / 2.0), 2)))
}
```

Please double check that I copied the equation correctly.

Comment: I'd also investigate using the `postgis geometry` type (which is supported by `slick-pg`) for doing distance calculations.

Comment: The equation looks good. I'm just getting an error with ` 3956 * 2 * ..`
It's having an issue with finding the symbol for "*"

Comment: may be a bug. please provide a reproducible example and report at https://github.com/slick/slick/issues